# can apache-log4j-extras jar be used with apache log4j 2.x

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Can apache-log4j-extras jar be used with apache log4j 2.x jars, or is it deprecated?

found the jar to be last updated in 1.2.17 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Apache Log4j 1.2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) Log4j 1.x has reached End of Life in **2015**, [Apache Log4j Extras](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) and **libraries with Log4j 1.2 components should be considered deprecated**.

All features provided by *Apache Log4j Extras* should be available in the [reference implementation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api-separation.html) of the Log4j2 API and other implementations (such as [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/)).

**PS**: For completeness' sake, the [Log4j 1.2 to Log4j2 API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge) bridge **does** support native Log4j 1.2 components (works only if the underlying implementation is Log4j2 Core) and as a proof-of-concept I have successfully run the `RollingFileAppender` from Apache Extras. This usage is however **not** advised since native Log4j2 Core components perform much better.

If you just use the Log4j 1.2 configuration format, since 2.18.0 (cf. [LOG4J2-3483](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3483)), we added a configuration builder that recognizes the `RollingFileAppender` from Apache Extras and builds a **Log4j2 native** [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) with the same configuration properties.